# Dingit.tv process running in Safari, using 1GB memory and 15% cpu

Tags: safari, memory

There's a process running in Safari (9.0.3) which is killing performance on my MBA. It's called dingit.tv and it's using between 1-2 GB RAM. As far as I know I've never been to this site. If I kill the process it just reappears immediately.

It seems like a virus to me. Anyone else seen this or know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running Dingit's uninstaller here:

http://kb.dingit.tv/article/114-how-do-i-uninstall-the-dingit-infinitehd-plugin

On OSX 10.10.5 when I browsed to the site the following appeared in the Activity Monitor:

```
http://www.dingit.tv
```

and it's actually just a window that's open in Safari and Safari will keep reopening it each time you kill it. The easy way to bring it onto the screen is to use the Merge All Windows option in Safari's Window menu and then close it.